# Docker bind mount issue in windows 10 linux image

Tags: node.js, docker, windows-10, dockerfile

I have an issue where docker doesn't sync up with my file change, Even though I have enabled shared volumes and added bind mount.

My current system
Windows 10 pro
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962

error message while docker build

> SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against
>   a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build
>   context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to
>   double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and
>   directories.

This is for a windows 10 machine, I've tried with the following file.

FROM node:8.11

```
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn
COPY . .

docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  app_web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:4000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a standard warning message for docker/windows and doesn't imply error.

For your case, use absolute host path in docker compose file instead of "." and see if that works. Also, you will need to enable drive sharing first from docker for windows menu.